# "Timestamp with Time Zone" type in Oracle retains timezone format

Tags: sql, oracle, formatting, timestamp-with-timezone

[Timestamp with Time Zone](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch4datetime.htm#i1006081) data type in Oracle has this weird feature where it retains the format of timezone from insertion when we select it without any formatting;

1. With `TZR`

   ```
   UPDATE X SET COLUMN_A = TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('19-JUL-18 01.53.16.381566000 PM UTC', 
                                           'DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZR') ...
   ```

   If I select this column directly;

   ```
   > SELECT COLUMN_A WHERE ...
   19-JUL-18 01.53.16.381566000 PM UTC
   ```
2. With `TZH:TZM`

   ```
   UPDATE X SET COLUMN_A = TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('19-JUL-18 01.53.16.381566000 PM +00:00', 
                                           'DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZH:TZM') ...
   ```

   If I select this column directly;

   ```
   > SELECT COLUMN_A WHERE ...
   19-JUL-18 01.53.16.381566000 PM +00:00
   ```

What is the reason behind this feature, and is there a way to control this such a way that, I can set all such values to `TZH:TZM` formatting for example. I am not talking about session specific `NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT`, even though it is pretty useful for `SELECT` cases

Comment: I think default display format depends on tool you are using for retrieving the data. Is it SQL*Plus ot Toad or what?

Comment: @Rusty it's [SQL Developer](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/sql-developer.html), but I think you misread the question, as explained above, the resulting format only depends on the format in the updates, in same tool, we get two different results with raw `SELECT`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Time zone `UTC` is different to time zone `+00:00`. You just get what you have inserted before.

Maybe the answer is more clear when I say: "Time zone `Europe/Zurich` is different to time zone `+02:00`." Currently both are 2 hour ahead UTC, in that manner they are equal. However in winter season this will change.

Neither `UTC` nor `+00:00` apply daylight saving times, so the difference is not so obvious but internally they are different.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I've got your problem but I still think it depends on tool. In my toad following test-case returns same result:

```
create table test_a(
  id        number,
  column_a timestamp with time zone
)
;

insert into test_a(id) values(1);
insert into test_a(id) values(2);

update test_a
SET COLUMN_A = TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('19-JUL-18 01.53.16.381566000 PM UTC', 
                                   'DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZR') 
where id = 1;                                   

update test_a
 SET COLUMN_A = TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('19-JUL-18 01.53.16.381566000 PM +00:00', 
                                   'DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZH:TZM') 
where id = 2;                                   


select * from test_a;
        ID COLUMN_A                           
---------- -----------------------------------
COLUMN_B                           
-----------------------------------
         1 2018-07-19 13:53:16.381566 +00:00  


         2 2018-07-19 13:53:16.381566 +00:00  



2 rows selected.
```

Comment: Can you select them individually? Does it have the same result?

Comment: TOAD has its own method to display data values (mainly it depends on your current Windows settings), you should not use it as reference. Use SQLplus. In SQLplus value from `NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT` applies